# Updating HTMLTextAreaElement value property did not update ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

Updated the HTMLTextAreaElement value property but the ngModel is not updated.

I notice there is a ng-model-options in angular.

Anything I need to specify in the option for the ngModel to update?

```
target: HTMLTextAreaElement = null;
appendToTarget(specialCharacters: UnicodeCharacter) {
    this.target.value = this.target.value.concat(specialCharacters);
}
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe angular doesn't know the value change, try $apply() or do that in a angular style.

In angular 2+

```
target: HTMLTextAreaElement = null;
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
appendToTarget(specialCharacters: UnicodeCharacter) {
    this.target.value = this.target.value.concat(specialCharacters);
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: i am using angular2

Comment: Do not work. The ngModel still did not update until i use the keyboard to enter character into the textbox.

Comment: There is another way to avoid this problem.  Concat the specialCharacters to this.textAreaValue(the ngModel for target) directly in function appendToTarget(){}

Comment: I don't have access to the ngmodel. This component is triggered on every input fields to add special characters.